# How can I mark some lines of my code as it won't run in release?

Tags: c#

I want to throw exceptions while debugging but in release mode I don't want to throw them. I am logging them into EventLog. This is the source of my problem but if I'm not wrong in C and Delphi there are some directives to make this.

In C# is there any way(directives or something else) which can ignore the lines in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: You might be interested in this article; people are sometimes confused by the difference between conditional compilation and the conditional attribute: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/what-s-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, you can have DEBUG defined in a release version, and not defined in a debug version. You'd be crazy to do that, but worth checking the build settings if you inherit a project, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

For your purposes (logging), you might also be interested in the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx). It lets you mark an entire *method* as "remove all calls to this method in release builds".

If you do your logging in a lot of different places in your code, this would be much simpler than adding `#if DEBUG` around every single call site.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `#if DEBUG` directive (and end with `#endif`). The DEBUG constant is defined when you run your application in debug mode (the *Define DEBUG constant* should be checked under the *Build* tab of your project properties).

Comment: Thank you but in example code piece would be better. Thank you for explanation but at least one link would be perfect.

Comment: @uzay95: Check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8476713/825024) written by *recursive*.